# count records with conditions

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, conditional-statements

I have a 2 models: User and Activity

Relationship between User and Activity is:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base    
  has_many :activities, :through => :projects
end
```

I want to count all users who signed in within the last 3 months (last_sign_in_at) with at least 5 activities. Here is what I have so far:

```
a=User.where(:admin => false)
a.joins(:activities).size
```

How do I restrict timeframe and get only those with 5+ activities? At the end I want to call .size to get a single result (not an array). Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a `counter_cache` (described in [the documentation for `belongs_to`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-belongs_to)) to store the count of the activities in the `users` table. Then:

```
User.where(:admin => false).where("created_at >= ?", 3.months.ago).where("activities_count >= 5)
```

This will find all the users who aren't admins, who were created at a time greater than or equal to ("within the") last 3 months who have an `activities_count` (this is the `counter_cache`field) greater than or equal to 5 (my interpretation of "5+).

Sound good? :)